# MySQL query with LEFT JOIN and LIKE conditions doesn't show what I expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join, sql-like

I'm trying to make a query that return data from 4 tables, the problem comes when I try to put some aditional conditions. The query works with 4 tables with LEFT JOIN without the conditions but when I put the LIKE condition nothing change in the result. The result must be the select with "lat" that only begins with 40.95

This code it's working:

```
if($resultset=getSQLResultSet("SELECT name, lat, lng, description, 
COALESCE(section, 0), COALESCE(AVG(score), 0) FROM places P LEFT JOIN ratings R ON P.id=R.place LEFT JOIN ratings_sections RS ON R.id=RS.rating LEFT JOIN categories C ON P.type=C.type GROUP BY P.name, RS.section ORDER BY P.name, RS.section")){
while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
    echo json_encode($row);
    }
}
```

But nothing change when I put the LIKE condition:

```
if($resultset=getSQLResultSet("SELECT name,lat, lng, description, COALESCE(section, 0), COALESCE(AVG(score), 0) FROM places P LEFT JOIN ratings R ON P.id=R.place AND P.lat LIKE '40.95%' LEFT JOIN ratings_sections RS ON R.id=RS.rating LEFT JOIN categories C ON P.type=C.type GROUP BY P.name, RS.section ORDER BY P.name, RS.section")){
    while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}
```

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM1eW.jpg)

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Also never ask a question stating something "doesn't work". Be explicit in how it doesn't work.

Comment: you are using UNION between tow select that return different number (and type) of column  ... union work only when the select involved  contain the same number and tyoe of coumn  .. in corresponding order

Comment: @scaisEdge neither UNION ALL? So, How can I join two table with different columns and with some LIKE conditions? Because LEFT JOIN it doesn't working for me either

Comment: you should update  your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. (union all return all rows  .. UNION only distinct rows) so you question about UNION ALL is unapplicable  ..  show us what you really need  .. and don't tell us just  .. don't work ..

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for the advice! I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL UNION ALL operator is used to combine the result sets of 2 or more SELECT statements.

```
SELECT name,lat, lng, description,... FROM
```

and

```
SELECT score FROM
```

Are different

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Raquel If its not working, why is this answer accepted

Comment: Because it's telling me that I can't use UNION ALL when the columns are differents @RiggsFolly I didn't know about that

Comment: @Raquel in that case Ildar's answer is a much better answer: more explicit and with some explanation. If I were you I'd accept his/her answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your third query is wrong, because you're making a `UNION` of two queries, where the first one consists of four columns, and the second one has just one column.

```
SELECT name, lat, lng, description
FROM places P, categories C
WHERE P.lat LIKE '40.96%'
OR lat LIKE '40.95%'
AND P.type=C.type
GROUP BY P.name
UNION
SELECT score
FROM ratings_sections RS, rating R
WHERE RS.rating=R.id
```

Your fourth query is also wrong, for example, here:

```
LEFT JOIN GROUP BY P.name, RS.section ORDER BY P.name, RS.section
```

You can't use a `GROUP BY` clause inside a `JOIN` for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about UNION ALL, but I've just tried and It doesn't work.

Comment: And also I make a mistake deleting some code before posting in the fourth query, sorry is my first time here

Comment: @Raquel glad it helped!